# Json object response in kotlin

Tags: android, json, object, kotlin

I am facing issue in get response in kotlin. My json response is:

```
{
   "message":"Success",
   "status":false,
   "data":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "username":"doctor",
         "phone":null,
         "speciality":"General Physician",
         "name":"Doctor",
         "firstname":null,
         "lastname":null,
         "gender":"",
         "age":null,
         "dobirth":null,
         "email":"doctor@live.com",
         "country":"Pakistan",
         "state":"Punjab",
         "city":"Lahore",
         "address":null,
         "affiliation":"",
         "degree":"MBBS",
         "bio":null,
         "password":"$2y$10$KF1zBxe07nPBW.0hFWiFfOjIur4cYYfP.LlQlujjcHq4WmQMLGWLK",
         "remember_token":"UlekRgPJqWPx9AczdW2D7cyjiWkyU4mDpGYkR2QYovjsDCaVTt7adnQmSJQo",
         "image":"1496739459-ariba.jpg",
         "license_owner":"0",
         "status":"0",
         "switch_role":"1",
         "invitation_code":"",
         "created_at":"2018-10-01 07:55:47",
         "updated_at":"2018-01-26 00:02:50",
         "license_purchase_id":"0",
         "profile_active":"0",
         "pmdc":"",
         "flag":"1"
      },
      {
         "id":"2",
         "username":"khawarshah",
         "phone":null,
         "speciality":"",
         "name":"Syed Khawar",
         "firstname":null,
         "lastname":null,
         "gender":"",
         "age":null,
         "dobirth":null,
         "email":"jjshjasd@tech4lifeenterprises.com",
         "country":"",
         "state":"",
         "city":"",
         "address":null,
         "affiliation":"",
         "degree":"",
         "bio":null,
         "password":"$2y$10$3nG\/43tUdA2QKzinBPvA4.zqQHfxmR8sZ0LICQ3xg6LLr6mFYZq7q",
         "remember_token":"teuzY7HKubHdQg9TXA3zgDJmszrNPm2vBg1226JmDPhk0APZuEafIUpNGKJ4",
         "image":"",
         "license_owner":"0",
         "status":"1",
         "switch_role":"1",
         "invitation_code":"",
         "created_at":"2019-04-19 07:08:10",
         "updated_at":"2019-04-19 11:08:10",
         "license_purchase_id":"0",
         "profile_active":"0",
         "pmdc":"",
         "flag":"1"
      }
  ]
}
```

ApiClient class and ApiFactory is[image]

[image]

```
data class Users (

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("message")
    val message: String,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("status")
    val status: String,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: String,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("username")
    val username: String,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("speciality")
    val speciality: String,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("firstname")
    val firstname: String,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("name")
    val name: String,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("lastname")
    val lastname: String,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("gender")
    val gender: String,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("age")
    val age: String,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("dobirth")
    val dobirth: String,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("email")
    val email: String,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("image")
    val image: String,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("switch_role")
    val switch_role: String

)
```

And Main fragment is

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel

    lateinit var progerssProgressDialog: ProgressDialog
    var dataList = ArrayList<Users>()
    lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    lateinit var adapter:ListAdapter


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        val RecyclerView: RecyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        recyclerView.adapter= ListAdapter(dataList,requireContext())
        recyclerView.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)

        progerssProgressDialog=ProgressDialog(requireContext())
        progerssProgressDialog.setTitle("Loading")
        progerssProgressDialog.setCancelable(false)
        progerssProgressDialog.show()
        getData()

        return root
    }


    private fun getData() {
        val call: Call<List<Users>> = ApiClient.getClient.getPhotos()
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Users>> {

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Users>>?, response: Response<List<Users>>?) {
                progerssProgressDialog.dismiss()
                dataList.addAll(response!!.body()!!)

                recyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Users>>, t: Throwable) {
                progerssProgressDialog.dismiss()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

but did not get response in recyclerview. what is the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with your data class "Users".. Check below data class for your reference:

```
data class Response(

@field:SerializedName("data")
val data: List<DataItem?>? = null,

@field:SerializedName("message")
val message: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("status")
val status: Boolean? = null)

data class DataItem(

@field:SerializedName("country")
val country: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("firstname")
val firstname: Any? = null,

@field:SerializedName("invitation_code")
val invitationCode: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("flag")
val flag: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("gender")
val gender: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("city")
val city: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("pmdc")
val pmdc: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("bio")
val bio: Any? = null,

@field:SerializedName("created_at")
val createdAt: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("switch_role")
val switchRole: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("speciality")
val speciality: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("password")
val password: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("updated_at")
val updatedAt: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("affiliation")
val affiliation: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("license_owner")
val licenseOwner: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("id")
val id: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("state")
val state: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("remember_token")
val rememberToken: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("email")
val email: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("image")
val image: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("license_purchase_id")
val licensePurchaseId: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("address")
val address: Any? = null,

@field:SerializedName("profile_active")
val profileActive: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("degree")
val degree: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("lastname")
val lastname: Any? = null,

@field:SerializedName("phone")
val phone: Any? = null,

@field:SerializedName("name")
val name: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("dobirth")
val dobirth: Any? = null,

@field:SerializedName("age")
val age: Any? = null,

@field:SerializedName("username")
val username: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("status")
val status: String? = null
```

)

Comment: And which Model class i use Response or DataItem in Main class?

Comment: just replace your users class with above code i have edited

Comment: Also you can install RoboPOJOGenerate from File->Settings->Plugins->Search RoboPOJOGenerate and install..
After successfull installation, right click on your package->New->Generate POJO from Json(at bottom).. Just copy paste ur json response and generate the class

Answer (score 1):

Your data classes and JSON structure don't match.

Use [JsonToKotlinClass](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass-) plugin to create data class from json in Android Studio

Comment: Super Helpful, Thanks. Kinda new to the whole classes types

Answer (score 0):

Your `Users` class does not match the structure of your json, so you won't be able to parse it. Looking at your json, it's more like:

```
data class ResponseMessage(
    val message: String,
    val status: Boolean,
    val data: List<User>
)

data class User(
    val id: Long,
    val username: String,
    ...
)
```